# www rewrite with excluded subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

I have a website that rewrites a non www url to a www url.

Therefor this condition is used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This code is basically "rewrite everything that doesn't start with www", because of the exclamation mark.
The problem is that with this code a subdomain at my website, let's say *subdomain.mysite.com* is also rewritten and becomes *www.subdomain.mysite.com*.

I tried adding this to prevent the subdomain from being rewritten, but It doesn't seem to do the trick completely...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

how can I rewrite my adress without affecting the subdirectory.

Comment: Without affecting **all** subdomains? Or just some of them?

Comment: It is just one subdomain, so I tried it with this also:  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\. [NC] but it seems to be an infinite loop (so firefox tells me...)

Comment: Do you have other subdomains which need the www. part?

Comment: The website has only one subdomain. So everything should be rewritten except that one subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @HansVn: It should work. Test in a different browser or clear the browser cache.

Comment: @HansVn: also note, my suggestion is a complete replacement for your redirects, not in addition to them...

Comment: It was working all the time... I did clear the browsers cache, but the htaccess file was still in the servers cache, so it took a while before I figured out it worked :) thanks!